# How to implement a serial data receiving event when the device sends frames of data?

Tags: serial-port, c++-cli

I have made an application to receive data from a serial port, I am able to receive data with the DataReceived event just fine.

The device doesn't send just bytes however, it sends frames that look like "#" + 16 byte data + ";" where # is STX and ; is ETX.

How do I implement this properly?  I only want to process the data when such a frame is received correctly.  The DataReceived event doesn't help me get this implemented since it fires for each byte, not for a frame of data.

Comment: What problem you're facing as of now ? Are you totally out of thoughts ? Show use what you tried ? If you didn't its simply will be assumed that you're here for getting free code.

Answer (score 1):

Some sample code to play with.  Initialize the class by passing an opened SerialPort object to its constructor.  You need to subscribe its DataReceived event to receive data.  Use ErrorReceived for diagnostics.  Events are raised on the UI thread, if you have one.  Untested code, ought to be in the ball-park.

```
public ref class SerialProtocol {
private:
    array<Byte>^ buffer;
    bool gotStx, warnStx;
    int bufcnt;
    SerialPort^ port;
    System::Threading::SynchronizationContext^ context;
    const int framesize = 16;
    const Byte STX = 2;
    const Byte ETX = 3;

public:
    SerialProtocol(SerialPort^ Port) :
        buffer(gcnew array<Byte>(framesize)),
        bufcnt(0), gotStx(false), warnStx(false),
        context(System::Threading::SynchronizationContext::Current),
        port(Port) {
        Port->DataReceived += gcnew SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this, &SerialProtocol::DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    event ErrorReceivedHandler^ ErrorReceived;
    event DataReceivedHandler^ DataReceived;

private:
    void DataReceivedHandler(Object^ sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^ e) {
        while (port->BytesToRead > 0) {
            Byte b = port->ReadByte();
            if (!gotStx) {
                // Need to see STX as start of frame now
                gotStx = b == STX;
                if (!gotStx && warnStx) OnProtocolViolated(ProtocolViolation::BadStx);
                warnStx = false;
                bufcnt = 0;
            }
            else if (bufcnt == buffer->Length) {
                // Got the frame data, need to see ETX now
                gotStx = false;
                warnStx = b == ETX;
                if (b == ETX) OnDataReceived();
                else OnProtocolViolated(ProtocolViolation::BadEtx);
            }
            else {
                // Busy receiving frame data
                buffer[bufcnt++] = b;
            }
        }
    }
    void OnProtocolViolatedHelper(Object^ state) {
        ErrorReceived(safe_cast<ProtocolViolation>(state));
    }
    void OnDataReceivedHelper(Object^ state) {
        DataReceived(safe_cast<array<Byte>^>(state));
    }

protected:
    virtual void OnProtocolViolated(ProtocolViolation error) {
        // Fires the ErrorReceived event
        if (context == nullptr) ErrorReceived(error);
        else context->Post(gcnew System::Threading::SendOrPostCallback(this, &SerialProtocol::OnProtocolViolatedHelper), error);
    }
    virtual void OnDataReceived() {
        // Fires the DataReceived event
        if (context == nullptr) DataReceived(buffer);
        else {
            // Keep the buffer threadsafe
            array<Byte>^ data = buffer;
            buffer = gcnew array<Byte>(framesize);
            context->Post(gcnew System::Threading::SendOrPostCallback(this, &SerialProtocol::OnDataReceivedHelper), data);
        }
    }
};
```